# Linq to SQL: Same stored procedure returns dynamic columns based on param

Tags: linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql, diff

Sales need to search by `ClientID`, `DivisionID` and `ProductID`. The UI simply has

- a drop-down list of "Client", "Division" and "Product", (@paramType)
- a text box for user to type-in an ID. (paramVal)

A stored procedure `SP1` is called to return different columns, and the number of columns are different too based on parameters: `@paramType`, `@paramVal`.

It's easy in the past w/o Linq. Linq defines fixed number of columns. There is a thread back in 2013 has partial solution. I'm wondering if someone has done it lately? For example there is [Table(Name="dbo.table1")], [Table(Name="dbo.table2")] and [Function(Name="dbo.SP")] in the designer.cs file, and I can define table(s) in the left pane of `.dbml` file. But how to tell

```
public ISingleResult<SP> SP(...)
```

when the returned is table1 or table2?

Comment: I would consider it a really **bad practice** to return varying shapes of result sets from a single stored procedure. This here is just one of the many reasons why. Don't do this - if you have three different sets of results - create three separate procedures.... don't make one "do-it-all" procedure - it's bad, it's really hard to maintain over time - just horrible design. Don't do it - seriously.

Comment: Typically, a SP is dedicated for one purpose.
However, there could be many situation varying shape of resultset is needed. A good sample is SQL profiler column list, a user can check or un-check a column based on his need. 

Similarly, the sales UI is one. Without LINQ, binding a dataset returned from a SP to a grid w/ auto-gen columns is never a problem. In fact, the drop-down is not limited to three choices. If the query logic is sophisticated, dedicated ones is the way to go, otherwise multiple IF... ELSE would have taken care of the need.

Comment: I'm an old school, TSQL stored proc is way better than LINQ.